# What is this colorful bug from Germany?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

a friend found this little fella just outside of Berlin and managed to snap a blurry picture.
[image]

This boy or girl is probably the size of a finger nail and features fly like skin wings with no hard cover. There are thin curved antennas at the head.

On the internet I found the same color scheme in "Festive Tiger Beetle (Cicindela scutellaris)", but the shape doesn't seem to match.

Can you identify this creature?
(surely not spider, right?)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you please provide some sense of scale - approximately how big do you think the insect is? With the poor photo, it is hard to tell if it is winged, or any features besides the distinctive colouration. Any further details you could provide would be useful in ID.

Comment: Festive tiger beetle seems to be only north America, though I am no expert.

Comment: It could be a [ruby-tailed wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysis_ignita).

Comment: That sounds indeed quite possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's some form of jewel beetle. Their wings are traditionally used in jewel and clothesmaking and some of them are detrimental invasive species.

It will be nearly impossible to say which species based on that photo, which is too blurry.

https://www.lsuagcenter.com/profiles/lbenedict/articles/page1590086881287

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buprestidae